# What's someones preferred method for adding a comments section to a TableViewCell?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am currently using a tableview to display a individual "Posts." In each tableview cell is a unique Post. I would like to add a collection of "comments" into each cell. The only way I can think about collecting comments is to add another TableView inside the Post's cell. What is some preferred methods to accomplishing this? It seems pretty complicated to use a TableView inside another TableViews Cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea.

Create N sections in your table view, one section for every post.

For every section

- the cell at row `0` will be populated with the post data
- every cell in the following rows will be populated with the comments data.

### Example

```
struct PostModel {
    let title: String
    let comments: [String]
}

class Posts: UITableViewController {
    private var posts: [PostModel] = ... // TODO

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts[section].comments.count + 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let post = posts[indexPath.section]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StandardCell") ?? UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "StandardCell")

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = post.title
            return cell
        } else {
            let comment = post.comments[indexPath.row-1]
            cell.textLabel?.text = comment
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I will have to look into how sections work. Thank you for your input!

Comment: @CoderCody: I added I simple code snippet to my answer to better describe the idea.

Comment: I was on my mobile device, didn't notice it. Thanks again.

Comment: So I am using two different Custom Cells, one for my image and post information. The other displays the comments. I have the Custom Cells setup in storyboard and am using the reuse identifier to access them. The problem I am running into is the Cell with the picture is not resizing to fit picture. It seem like the cell size will not adjust at all. Is this because I am working with more then one section?

Comment: @CoderCody: No, this is not related to the multiple sections. Try this: in Storyboard select the prototype cell, then open the `Size Inspector` `alt + cmd + 5`, select `Custom` and make sure the cell has the correct height. Then repeat for the second prototype cell.

Comment: Everything is set to custom and the proper size. Table view cell is still regular tableview cell size:(